# CSS Sprite now showing once uploadedhtr

Tags: html, css, ftp, css-sprites

http://www.keironlowe.host56.com/Website%20Testing/index.html

At the bottom below the paragraph of text I have two images with hover effects one says Contact us and another says Jobs Available!

These are there when I test the site on my local machine, but when I upload them to a server there not there when I load the page, the anchors are still there you can see that when you hover over them, just not the images.

What's wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first problem is that you are trying to use a background image to express content. If you really need a picture, then it should be an `<img>` element (with an alt attribute).

The second problem is that "http://www.keironlowe.host56.com/Website%20Testing/IMG/CTAButtons.png" is a 301 redirect to "http://error.000webhost.com/", which doesn't seem to be responding.

Comment: Thanks for the help, how would I stop the images being a 301 redirect?

Also the problem with your first comment is that you cannot use <img> for css sprites

Comment: It depends why the images are being treated as a 301 in the first place. That is a matter of server configuration. (And that just means "Don't use sprites for this")